# Vue method being called twice on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use Vue inputs to record some simple data, but for some reason the method `add()` called by the button gets called twice.

```
    <el-steps :active="addItem.count" finish-status="success" class="form-items" style="padding-left: 0px">
        <el-step title="category"></el-step>
        <el-step title="subcategory"></el-step>
        <el-step title="data"></el-step>
    </el-steps>   
    <el-form ref="form" :model="addItem" label-width="120px" style="padding: 20px;">
        <el-input :placeholder="placeholder" v-model="addItem.text"></el-input>
        <div id="add-item-buttons">
        <el-form-item  class="form-items">
            <el-button type="primary" @click="add">Create</el-button>
            <el-button>Clear</el-button>
        </el-form-item>
        </div>
    </el-form>
```

```
<script>
export default {

     methods: {
     add(){
         switch(this.addItem.count){
         case 1:
             this.addItem.category = this.addItem.text;
             console.log('category set to: ' + this.addItem.category);
             this.addItem.text = '';
             this.addItem.count++;

         case 2:
             this.addItem.subcategory = this.addItem.text;
             console.log('category set to: ' + this.addItem.subcategory);
             this.addItem.text = '';
             this.addItem.count++;
         case 3:
             if (this.addItem.kks.show){
             this.addItem.kks.name = this.addItem.text;
             }
             if (this.addItem.document.show){
             this.addItem.document.name = this.addItem.text;
             }
             if (this.addItem.product.show){
             this.addItem.product.name = this.addItem.text;
             }
         }

     },
     computed: {
     placeholder: function(){
         switch(this.addItem.count){
         case 1:
             return 'ADD A CATEGORY TO YOUR ITEM';
         case 2:
             return 'ADD A SUBCATEGORY TO YOUR ITEM';
         case 3:
             return 'GIVE YOUR ITEM A NAME';
         }
     },
     active: function(){
         return true;
     }
     },
     data() {
     return {
         addItem: {
           open: false,
           count: 1,
           category: '',
           subcategory: '',
           text: ''
          }
      }       
...   
</style>
```

Here's what I see in the console when I click 'create':

```
category set to: category 1
category set to:
```

Edit: turns out I made a typo and wrote 'category set to' for my second switch case where I meant 'subcategory'.  So apparently, both Case 1 and Case 2 are being evaluated, not Case 1 twice.  Here's the new console log when it's fixed:

```
category set to: category 1
(unknown) subcategory set to:
```

And instead of switching to ADD YOUR SUBCATEGORY, it goes straight to ITEM.

Can anyone see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your switch case statement is missing breaks.

You increse your counter by one and the second condition is matching aswell. Simply add breaks and you ll be fine

```
switch(this.addItem.count){
     case 1:
         this.addItem.category = this.addItem.text;
         console.log('category set to: ' + this.addItem.category);
         this.addItem.text = '';
         this.addItem.count++;
         break;

     case 2:
         this.addItem.subcategory = this.addItem.text;
         console.log('category set to: ' + this.addItem.subcategory);
         this.addItem.text = '';
         this.addItem.count++;
         break;
     case 3:
         if (this.addItem.kks.show){
             this.addItem.kks.name = this.addItem.text;
         }
         if (this.addItem.document.show){
             this.addItem.document.name = this.addItem.text;
         }
         if (this.addItem.product.show){
             this.addItem.product.name = this.addItem.text;
         }
         break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Guess I needed to review switch statements.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.